# Get rid of fields added by angular $resource with $promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If you use resource together with promise:

```
$resource('api/items').get(items).$promise.then((items) => {
    $scope.items = items
}
```

Turns out it wraps `items` in `Result` object and adds some additional fields. This does not affect the app itself, but fucks up the tests:

```
httpBackend.expectGET('api/items').respond(200, items);
controller.getItems();
httpBackend.flush();
expect(controller.items).toEqual(items);
```

which results in error:

```
Expected [ Resource({ items: [...], $promise: Promise({ $$state: Object({ status: 1, pending: undefined, value: <circular reference: Object>, processScheduled: false }) }), $resolved: true }) ] to equal [ Object({ items: [...] }) ].
```

Why angular adds this fields and how can I get rid of this $promise,$resolved etc. junk to make my tests clean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout the Returns section for the resource docs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

Look for the toJson function, that should help you out as it strips off the angular fields for you

A simpler way is that as you get an angular resource object back you could just assign scope.items whatever the property is on the resource that holds the data. E.g:

```
$scope.items = resource.items;
```

This will pass the test for you and is what I typically do when using ngresource as this is all that get used by my view controllers